# Issue while printing 2 pages from a WKWebView

Tags: ios, objective-c, printing, wkwebview

**The requirement:** I have a `WKWebview` object called `wkWebView`. I want to print its contents from my printer using Airprint. I used to do this using `UIWebview` but the requirement of runtime javascript methods made me switch to `WKWebview`.

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) WKWebView *wkWebView;
```

**The problem:** I am able to print the contents using the code below. When I print 1 page it prints perfectly. But *when I try to print 2 pages, the 2nd page prints first and then after that the 1st page prints.* I want to print the pages in serial order.

**The code:**  I am currently using this code in my print method:

```
UIPrintInfo *pi = [UIPrintInfo printInfo];
pi.outputType = UIPrintInfoOutputGrayscale;
pi.orientation = UIPrintInfoOrientationPortrait;
pi.duplex = UIPrintInfoDuplexNone;


UIPrintInteractionController *pic = [UIPrintInteractionController sharedPrintController];
pic.printInfo = pi;
pic.showsPageRange = YES;
pic.showsNumberOfCopies = NO;
pic.printFormatter = _wkWebView.viewPrintFormatter;

UIButton *butn = (UIButton*)sender;

[pic presentFromRect:butn.frame
              inView:self.view
            animated:YES
   completionHandler:^(UIPrintInteractionController *printInteractionController, BOOL completed, NSError *error) {

       //Do something
   }];
```

Comment: I have tried your code with google search page and it works. It shows the pages in the correct order, so i suspect that you did something in another place in code that broke it. So can you show more code you have?

Comment: @MahmoudAdam: Instead of the google search page, I'm loading a local html file (in html string) in this webview. Not sure why this is happening.

Comment: Can you post the html as I think that the problem is on the html itself not the code

Answer (score -3):

Did you ever try to print the Pages seperately?

I would put them Pages in an Array, then check the array length and run the code to print the Page inside a For loop.